# Order DataTable after the population

Tags: vb.net, sorting, ado.net, datatable

I have a DataTable that I use to add, modify and delete data locally.
The DataTable is also used to populate a Grid.

I need to order the grid according to an integer value (importance).

I wanted to implement two buttons to increase or decrease the importance of each record.
For this reason I wrote this code:

```
 Dim rowNumber As Integer = 0

    For i As Integer = 0 To dataTable.Rows.Count - 1
        'search for the selected row in the DataGridView by ID
        If dataTable.Rows(i)("ID") = ID Then
            rowNumber= i
        End If
    Next

    If rowNumber <> 0 Then
        dataTable.Rows(rowNumber )("Priority") -= 1
        dataTable.Rows(rowNumber - 1)("Priority") += 1
    End If
```

It works fine the first time, it changes the selected record and makes changes to all the others to adjust the order. The second time it generates an error.

This because the DataTable is not automatically sorted according to the new Priority Order.

I would like to know if there is a way to sort the DataTable after changing the original order of the records (field Priority)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a DataView for that:

```
Dim dv As New DataView(dataTable)
dv.Sort = "Priority"
```

Then use the dv as the DataSource for the grid.

---

Based on your comments, I think you need to find the row that has the other priority number:

```
Dim rowNumber As Integer = 0
Dim priorityNumber As Integer = 0

For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
  If dt.Rows(i)("ID") = ID Then
    rowNumber = i
    priorityNumber = dt.Rows(i)("Priority")
    dt.Rows(i)("Priority") -= 1
  End If
Next

For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
  If dt.Rows(i)("ID") <> ID AndAlso dt.Rows(i)("Priority") = priorityNumber Then
    dt.Rows(i)("Priority") += 1
  End If
Next
```

Comment: unfortunately the problem is not the datagrid, that I can display properly.
The fact is that when I scroll the rows in the dataset for the second time, their order is old and not up to date!

Comment: @WannyMiarelli What is the error that is generated the second time using your code?

Comment: no error. Simply the loop modifies the wrong row. This is because in the datatable rows are ordered by ID and not by priority. The first time the product with ID = 1 is located at the third row, its priority is increased by 1 and the priority of the row previous decresed by 1.

the datatable is not updated with the new order

The second time you try to increase the priority of the product cycle 1 is wrong, because in the datatable product with ID = 1 is still in third place, whereas if it were sorted by priority would be  second.

Comment: @WannyMiarelli Then you can't use `rowNumber - 1` (which would cause an error on row 0).  You would have to do another search for the row that has the priority number you want to swap with.

Comment: it was so easy... :| Thank you LarsTech